# android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0 Error

Tags: android

I'm working with android upload services. Below code works fine in android 5.0. But when i try it on my android 9.0 device it occur error which i mention in title. I upload my code and please help to fix this.

**This is the code**

```
 public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String document_id = cursor.getString(0);
    document_id = document_id.substring(document_id.lastIndexOf(":") + 1);
    cursor.close();

    cursor = getContentResolver().query(
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            null, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + " = ? ", new String[]{document_id}, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
    cursor.close();

    return path;
}
```

**This is the error**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.solution.eapp.stockmanager, PID: 2265
android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 0
    at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:474)
    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
    at android.database.CursorWrapper.getString(CursorWrapper.java:137)
    at com.solution.eapp.stockmanager.PostAdActivity.getPath(PostAdActivity.java:192)
    at com.solution.eapp.stockmanager.PostAdActivity.uploadMultipart(PostAdActivity.java:120)
    at com.solution.eapp.stockmanager.PostAdActivity$3.onClick(PostAdActivity.java:109)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6608)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6585)
    at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:785)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25921)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
```

Thank you.

Comment: add the code snippet into the question instead of a link/image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should check before trying to access to the cursor

```
     public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);

        if (cursor.moveToNext() && cursor.getCount()>0) {
         cursor.moveToFirst();
         String document_id = cursor.getString(0);
         document_id = document_id.substring(document_id.lastIndexOf(":") + 1); 
         cursor.close();

        }
        cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                null, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + " = ? ", new String[]{document_id}, null);

       if (cursor.moveToNext() && cursor.getCount()>0) {
         cursor.moveToFirst();
         String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
        cursor.close();
    }
        return path;
    }
```

Comment: Could you rearrange the full code with your solution. Because i'm new in android programming. Thank you

Comment: I also tried that one. But the error was document_id and return path. Even i create those Strings outside to the if statements, error was gone but code not working

Comment: Then probably u're missing something related to New way of getting value from db for android 9 OS